# Understanding insertion in a linked list

Tags: java, methods, linked-list

I am having trouble understanding how to insert in a linked list.I've found some examples online but I can't seem to understand it 100%.In this code,I've put comments on what I think happens in the code,as well as with what I'm struggeling.Some help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
    private static final class Node {
        final Person person;
        Node next;

        Node(Person person) {
            this.person = person;
        }
    }

   public boolean insert(Person person) {
        Node n = new Node(person);
        //insert as the first element
        if (head == null) {
            head = n;
            size++;
            return true;
        }

        Node current = head;
        Node prev = null;
        int comparison;

        while (current != null) {
            //until the list is empty compare 
            comparison = person.name.compareTo(current.person.name);
            //that person already exists
            if (comparison == 0) {
                return false;
            } else if (comparison > 0) { 
                //if the next spot in the list is empty place the person there
                if (current.next == null) { 
                    current.next = n;
                    break;
                }
            } else { 
            //this is the part I dont understand
                if (prev == null) { 
                    Node oldHead = head;
                    head = n;
                    head.next = oldHead;
                    break;
                }
                //dont understand this either
                prev.next = n;
                n.next = current;
                break;
            }
            //keep moving through the list
            prev = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
        size++;
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on all of the comparisons you are doing in the code, it seems as if this is a sorted linked list and not a normal linked list.

This bit of code is saying that if the value being inserted is less than the head, we want this new value to be the head and the original head to be the second value in the list. Therefore oldHead is a reference variable to head just to temporarily hold the value. After that, head = n is just setting the head(aka the first node in the list) to the new node, so now the first node is the one being inserted. Then head.next = oldHead is setting the next value in the list equal to the original head of the list. Now the inserted value is first in the list and the original head is the second value in the list.

```
if (prev == null) { 
        Node oldHead = head;
        head = n;
        head.next = oldHead;
        break;
}
```

This bit of code is just setting the links so all the variables are linked together.

```
//dont understand this either
prev.next = n;
n.next = current;
break;
```

Comment: Oh,my bad I didnt say it was a sorted linked list, sorry! Thank you for the explanation.